# Make rigid body collide with hair particles

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, particles

I have a ground plane set up with a hair particle system, it is set as a passive rigid body.
Now I want to be able to drop my Active rigid bodies, and have them collide and lay on top of the hair.

Further more I'm trying to find a way to make the hair particles mat down where the rigid bodies hit them.

Comment: There is not really any way to do this properly (yet), but you can make the rigid-bodies affect the hair by enabling *Collision* on the rigid-bodies and *Hair Dynamics* on the particles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As gandalf3 said, you can enable **Collision** on the rigid bodies, and set **Hair Dynamics** in the hair particle setting. ([**demo file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26453))

You can also add [Force Field](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Force_Fields) to the Active rigid bodies to simulate the collision, since Hair particles react directly to force fields:

[image]