# Simple Collision Simulation issue

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation

I am very new to blender.
I am trying to make a rigid body and hair to collide, but they don`t, the hairs are just passing through.
When i googled it I could not find wrong i am doing. only one solution i got is to use force field. buts not what i want.
I am attaching my [blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7cRHtaGh00JSWFtY3BXV0NuRGs/edit?usp=sharing), please find me what is wrong.

Comment: Sort of duplication to [this one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6492/696).

Comment: force field around a human body would be ridiculous...... i think

Answer (score 1):

After checking the file, you need to tweak a few key options to make this work:

1. Set **Collider Friction** to a higher Value (maximum 1.000);
2. The cube (the active rigid body object) have to be subdivided to a higher resolution, the higher, the better, but slower.

[image]

**[Demo File](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27095)**

Comment: still didn't work

Comment: OK, see the updated demo file.

Comment: @rakeshmalik91 Btw, I wonder which version or build you were using for creating this file.

Comment: build i used is Blender 2.6.9

Comment: Would you please try [this file](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7348/696) with your current version to see if that problem still occurs? Because it seems to be a bug. Btw, Did you solve the problem in this answer? Try do it with the [latest offcial build](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.70/).

Comment: Well, if you are sure that it still didn't work even following my suggestion, just upload the adjusted file here. This is the simplest way to figure out what's left.