# Why hair particle system with same settings act differently?

Tags: physics, particles

As seen from the attached file, Plane A and Plane B have different hair particle system, but with exactly the same settings. However, they acted differently. I just wonder what caused it.

[**.blend file.**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27096)

[image]

Comment: Even when using the same particle system they behave differently! Perhaps a bug?

Comment: @gandalf3 Hmm, I'm not so sure, could probably be. Actually, Plane B came from [another question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7343/696).

Comment: I noticed blender crashed a couple of times after fiddling with the gravity settings (both scene and per particle system). I couldn't reproduce it consistently though.

Comment: strange, if I dupe PLane A using shift D. It behaves the same as plane A. How did you create plane B?

Comment: @Vader I'm also wondering how [he](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7343/696) created it. :\