# How to prevent hair particles from going through the mesh

Tags: mesh, particles, collision, hair

How can I prevent hair strands from going through the mesh in other way than using force field so the outcome is like A or B shown on the picture? I've tried using collision with hair dynamics but couldn't cope with that (cos I'm a newb probably, trying this method I got some very weird twisted hair results), maybe you can help with the explanation or some other ways than manual particle edit. I was looking for the answer for an hour and many people recommended collision on the mesh with hair dynamics but the instructions weren't clear or the result was not as expected. I'm using Blender 2.77

[image: hair collision]

Comment: I've tried to do something similar [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6487/2217).

Comment: I've already seen that post but it didn't help much. Also I've heard something about "kill particles" option but it does nothing as I play with the options by myself neither does the collision, which goes wild after couple frames into simulation or just doesn't give me expected effects (btw. yes I've applied rotation and scale)